# Get DIRECTIONS in Ionic Framework Google Map

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, dictionary, ionic-framework

How can I include directions in my map?

I'm working on ionic framework and this is my js that refer to a ionic.html file (index html just include scripts and position of ionic view). I have installed map and geolocation cordova plugin.

```
app.controller('MapController', function($scope, $ionicLoading) {

     // var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.3000, -120.4833);

      var mapOptions = {
          //center: myLatlng,
          zoom: 16,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
          map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
          var myLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude),
              map: map,
              title: "My Location"
          });
     // var newLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.3000, -120.4833);
      var torriLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(44.823889, 10.335894000000053),
              map: map,
              title: "My Location"
      });

      });


      $scope.map = map;
 });
```

For directions I mean "how I can reach a specific location by car, walking or bus?"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get direction of your movement then you want to check your position timely (after some time or position change). So use GetCurrentPostion with SetIntervale or WatchPosition method .Code will we like

```
setInterval( function(){
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success_loc, error_loc, opti)
    },(1000 * 60 * 1));
```

or `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition);`

Refer
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition

Comment: No sorry...I meant that I want to know, for example, how I can reach a specific location (by car, walking, bus...)

Comment: use travel mode option for this .. check out this sample https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/